# TabActivity GroupActivity Back button dont work

Tags: android, tabactivity, android-tabactivity

i have a problem with back button in tabactivity und grouptactivty.
i have 4 tab, in a tab i have there more 3 activity too. when i call a activity, it is withouts problems. but if i click to the back button, than my app close completle.

Here are my code. Where is my faullt.

Tabactivity

```
public class TabbarActivity extends TabActivity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabbar);



    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    Intent intent;
    Resources res = getResources();

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, HauptmenuActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("ReweHaupt")
            .setIndicator("ReweHaupt", 
                    res.getDrawable(R.drawable.home))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ContactGroupEinkaufliste.class);
    spec = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("EinkaufListe")
            .setIndicator("EinkaufListe",
                    res.getDrawable(R.drawable.einkaufliste))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, FilialesuchenActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("Filiarsuchen")
            .setIndicator("Filiarsuchen",
                    res.getDrawable(R.drawable.searchbuton))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, NotizblockActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("Einkaufzettel")
            .setIndicator("Einkaufzettel",
                    res.getDrawable(R.drawable.einkaufliste))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

}
```

ContactGroupEinkaufliste.java

```
public class ContactGroupEinkaufliste extends ActivityGroup {

public static ContactGroupEinkaufliste groupContact;


private ArrayList<View> history;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.history = new ArrayList<View>();
    groupContact = this;


    View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(
            "idHoraireActivity",
            new Intent(this, EinkauflisteActivity.class)
                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
            .getDecorView();


    replaceView(view);

}

public void replaceView(View v) {

    history.add(v);

    setContentView(v);
}

public void back() {
    if(history.size() > 0) {
        history.remove(history.size()-1);
        setContentView(history.get(history.size()-1));
    }else {
        finish();
    }
}

// @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    ContactGroupEinkaufliste.groupContact.back();
    return;
}}
```

EinkauflisteActivity.java

```
public class EinkauflisteActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.einkaufliste);

    Button btnsenden = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsenden);
    Button btnscaner = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnscaner);
    Button btnsuchen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsuchen);

    // wenn wir button clicken, rufen wir neu activity

    btnsuchen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View view = ContactGroupEinkaufliste.groupContact
                    .getLocalActivityManager()
                    .startActivity(
                            "suchenactivity",
                            new Intent(v.getContext(), SuchenActivity.class)
                                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
                    .getDecorView();
            ContactGroupEinkaufliste.groupContact.replaceView(view);
        }
    });

}}
```

SuchenActivity.java

```
public class SuchenActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.suchen);

}}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to manually handle the back keypress event. This technique is described here:

http://united-coders.com/nico-heid/use-android-activitygroup-within-tabhost-to-show-different-activity

Comment: Sorry but i havent found. where is this exactly?

Answer (score 0):

And what do you expect when clicking back button? Default action is go to previous activity. You have TabActivity as main - so you exit from your TabActivity. If you want change somehow default action just override `onBackPressed` in TabActivity. But be careful with it - changing default actions usually are not good for user experience.

Comment: you mean?
could i write in tabbaractivity onbackpressed ?

Answer (score 0):

try this in your TabActivity..

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Activity act = getCurrentActivity();
    act.onBackPressed();

    // super.onBackPressed();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that it is impossible to override Back button action in TabActivity.
You should do it in the hosted activities

```
@Override

         public void onBackPressed() {

             Log.i("Kishu","[onBackPressed()] pressed");
             getParent().moveTaskToBack(true); 
             return;

         }
```

In this example, pressing Back button will put your app to back. Default behaviour will close it.

**Note: you should put back you TabActivity, not hosted activity.**